# Controls not changing color in the first page of a report

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a sub that opens a report "eBouchTest". I loop through controls and change the controls' backcolors. I'm simplifying my question, eventually this will only happen based on a condition but for now I want every combobox, listbox or textbox colored grey.

When running the following piece of code, page 1 of my report does not have it's control's colors changed, but all the other pages do. Why is that so and how can I fix it? Clicking a button launches the following sub with no errors:

```
Sub ViewReport()
    Dim formname As String
    Dim ctl As Control
    Dim frm As Report

    formname = "eBouchTest"

    Set frm = Application.Reports(formname)

    DoCmd.openreport formname, acViewPreview

    For Each ctl In frm.Controls
            If ctl.ControlType = acTextBox Or ctl.ControlType = acComboBox Or ctl.ControlType = acListBox Then
                    ctl.BackColor = RGB(200, 200, 200)
            Debug.Print ctl.Name & " " & ctl.BackColor
        End If

    Next ctl

    Set ctl = Nothing

End Sub
```

Page 1 of the report (partial picture only for size purpose):
[image]

following pages:

[image]

**How can I make page 1 change colors as well?**

Answer (score 0):

AFIK, only way to effectively control dynamic appearance of controls on report with VBA is code in Format event of section the controls are in. Format events run only for Normal and Preview not Report view.

Can use custom Global variable or intrinsic OpenArgs to pass conditional value to the report. `DoCmd.openreport formname, acViewPreview, , , , "some value"`

Maybe Conditional Formatting would work for you. This will allow display in Report view. A CF rule can reference the OpenArgs parameter passed to report. Ex:
[image: Conditional Formatting Example]

Can simultaneously select all controls desire to have this rule and set the condition for all in one action.

CF is really the only way to change control appearance between records because VBA code sets property for ALL instances of the control. So if the condition depends on data in each record, use CF.

Comment: As stated in the question, "I'm simplifying my question, eventually this will only happen based on a condition but for now I want every combobox, listbox or textbox colored grey." I'm just trying to understand why it doesn't work for now, they won't ALL get coloured in the end...

Comment: Okay, sorry I forgot reading that when posting answer. See edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the code of formatting control in the detail_format event of report.

```
Private Sub Detail_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)

Dim formname As String

Dim ctl As Control

Dim frm As Report


formname = "eBouchTest"

Set frm = Application.Reports(formname)

For Each ctl In frm.Controls
        If ctl.ControlType = acTextBox Or ctl.ControlType = acComboBox Or ctl.ControlType = acListBox Then
                ctl.BackColor = RGB(200, 200, 200)
        Debug.Print ctl.Name & " " & ctl.BackColor
    End If

Next ctl

Set ctl = Nothing

End Sub
```

Also use a global variable to set the formatting of control dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

The first page will also be coloured if I refresh it in one way or another. In my case, the reports are displayed in Landscape mode in print preview, so at the end of the code, I just add

```
frm.Printer.Orientation = acPRORLandscape
```

which really doesn't change anything, but for some reason it colors the fields in without adding or changing anything else to the code.